# How to monitor your code execution written for any electronic device while they are operating?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, debugging, troubleshooting, code

I am working on a mobile robot that includes motors, proximity sensors, encoders, and MCU. I am powering my MCU [CC1350](https://www.ti.com/product/CC1350) Launchpad using the onboard power supply. The IDE I am using is [Energia IDE](https://energia.nu/), which is very similar to Arduino.

Sometimes I need to monitor the robot behavior when it takes a turn or some time I need to monitor sensor values or false triggering of sensors. For that I use the serial monitor of Energia IDE.

But according to Texas instrument I can either power it using external power using micro USB or using an on-board power supply or battery. For that a switch is also given on the launchpad to switch the way you power up the board.

My question is about how I can monitor values or see code execution while my robot is operating without any damage to my board or MCU. What is the standard way to do this?

Comment: your link to MCU is broken, but I googled its datasheet. It says it's an ARM MCU with JTAG. You want to look into how to use JTAG with it. It should be able to do just what you want.

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's impossible to use on-board power while the USB remains plugged in and the serial link remains active even though you're not using USB power?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to debug is to start an in-circuit emulation debug session. Look at the CC1350 block diagram, you will notice the JTAG block. This is an in-circuit debug feature using JTAG. Now notice the large chip near the micro-USB connector on the Launchpad board. This is not your CC1350 target chip, rather its there for JTAG and debug support, so you don't need external JTAG hardware, just a standard USB cable. The micro-USB connector on the Launchpad board is multi-purpose, (1) supplies power to the board, (2) provides debug feature, (3) optionally provides UART communications. So yes, you can power the board with the micro-USB **AND** debug using the same connector. I've used the Energia IDE only briefly once before, but with Code Composer Studio, you can output directly to the built-in console.

After you compile your project, connect the board to your PC and then click the debug icon, wait for the target to connect, then click run. To inspect variables, you need to decide where you want to place a breakpoint, or use the pause button to halt your program at any time to inspect variables. An alternate method (and better) is to use that UART channel on the debug support chip to supply you with values in real time. To use this feature, you need to configure the UART channel on the target chip, then modify your code to output data to the UART hardware.